# add column based on conditions and comparisons in other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to add additional columns in the data frame based on the conditions and comparison of values in existing columns.

This is the original data frame:

```
        start         end Sold
0                           NA
1  2017-05-08  2017-09-08  Yes
2  2018-09-01  2017-09-01  Yes
```

This is the data frame that I want:

```
        start         end Sold    valid
0                           NA  Unknown
1  2017-05-08  2017-09-08  Yes     True
2  2018-09-01  2017-09-01  Yes    False
```

Basically, the new column valid is defined by all 3 existing columns.

`Condition 1`: If sold is NA, valid equals to unknown.

`Condition 2`: If sold is not NA, start date < end date, valid equals to True. And valid equals to False is sold is not NA and start date > end date.

Can anyone suggest a piece of code?

Comment: Neither of what you want nor what you have are DataFrames.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
#convert to datetimes both columns
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'], errors='coerce')
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], errors='coerce')

df['valid'] = np.select([df['Sold'] == 'NA', 
                        df['start'] < df['end'], 
                        df['start'] > df['end']], ['Unknown', True, False])
```

If `Na` are missing values `NaN` test values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
df['valid'] = np.select([df['Sold'].isna(), 
                        df['start'] < df['end'], 
                        df['start'] > df['end']], ['Unknown', True, False])

print (df)
       start        end Sold    valid
0        NaT        NaT   NA  Unknown
1 2017-05-08 2017-09-08  Yes     True
2 2018-09-01 2017-09-01  Yes    False
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative.. use `np.where`

```
df['valid'] = np.where(df['Sold'] == 'NA', 'Unknown', 
         np.where((df['Sold'] != 'NA') &  (df['start'] < df['end']),True,
                  np.where((df['Sold'] != 'NA') &  (df['start'] > df['end']), False, '')))
```

If NA are missing `NaN`

```
df['valid'] = np.where(df['Sold'].isnull()==True, 'Unknown', 
         np.where((df['Sold'] != 'NA') &  (df['start'] < df['end']),True,
                  np.where((df['Sold'] != 'NA') &  (df['start'] > df['end']), False, '')))
```

**Output**

```
        start         end Sold    valid
0                           NA  Unknown
1  2017-05-08  2017-09-08  Yes     True
2  2018-09-01  2017-09-01  Yes    False
```